# CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such field" When Editing CiviMail

Tags: civimail

When I try to continue editing a CiviMail email we get the following error after upgrading to 4.6.4 from 4.5.5.

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: no such field"
#0 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Info.php(111): civicrm_api3("Mailing", "get", (Array:5))
#1 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php(130): CRM_Mailing_Info->getAngularModules()
#2 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Main.php(66): Civi\Angular\Manager->getModules()
#3 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Page/Main.php(58): Civi\Angular\Page\Main->registerResources()
#4 /home/ccsdfoundation/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): Civi\Angular\Page\Main->run((Array:2), NULL)
#5 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#6 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#7 /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#8 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("a")
#9 /home/sitename/public_html/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:1))
#10 /home/sitename/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

*No such field* errors after an upgrade are most commonly caused by not having run the DB upgrader.

- For Drupal, visit `?q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1` or `civicrm/upgrade?reset=1`
- For WordPress, visit `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1`
- For Joomla, visit `/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1`

For full upgrade advice and various troubleshooting tips, refer to [the upgrade documentation page for your CMS](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades).

Comment: I ran the upgrade and it completed without errors.

Comment: There's also a document on [ensuring schema integrity on upgrades](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Ensuring+Schema+Integrity+on+Upgrades)? The first step I'd take would be to compare the DB result of `SELECT version FROM civicrm_domain` against the version of the codebase you think is installed. If they don't match, you might have an incompletely upgraded codebase.

Comment: The version is  4.6.4 .

Comment: The databases match and I am not sure what I am doing with comparing the schema. I found this on GitHub but it is not setup for 4.6.4 https://github.com/progressivetech/civi-schema-harmonizer

Comment: I was able to get the schema harmonizer to work with some tinkering and the site is running well now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the GitHub project at github.com/progressivetech/civi-schema-harmonizer  with some tinkering to make it work.  I documented my tinkering in the issues for the git project.